# Accumulate with DAX (PowerBi)

Tags: powerbi, dax, report, powerquery, finance

I've got a table with a Balance column with integers. Let's say my starting balance is 120 000. I want to calculate Accumulated balance for all records. For e.g. my first record balance is -20 000 so my starting going to be 100 000, the next is +10 000 so the starting balance should be 110 000. I know that DAX variables are immutable, but i hope there is a solution for this problem. This is needed for my cashFlow diagram. It'd be nice if i only have to write 1 powerQuery to this problem.

I tried a few thing, but i could not write recursive custom function in DAX. I managed to do it in excel, but it'd be nice if i only have to use PowerBi for this problem. I read through the documentation but i did not find the correct answer for my problem.

Comment: Search for cumulative sums and time intelligence.